# Mui-datatables Material-UI: the page prop of a TablePagination is out of range

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui-datatable

I have created a minimal example [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-sea-on2zl) to show the problem/bug

Steps to reproduce:

- Go to [this link](https://on2zl.codesandbox.io/)
- Go to page 2
- Click the button on top of the page

What is happening is our `rowsPerPage` is 2 but we have 4 rows initially so we have 2 pages.

When we navigate to the second page (which is showing rows 3 & 4) everything is good till now, but when we change the table data to an array of 2 rows only, the table is re-rendered but still shows the second page (which is empty as our `newData` holds only 2 rows and our `rowsPerPage` is 2).

At that point you have to click the *left arrow* to go to the page where you'll see the `newData`

I hope I am clear enough, how can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like an open issue on their side in the latest version of the library.
If a downgrade to a lower version of the library can be an option for you, your code is working just fine with version `2.0.0` of `mui-datatables`.

Comment: Yeah I guess I'll downgrade until a fix comes, thank you. I opened an [issue](https://github.com/gregnb/mui-datatables/issues/698) on github

Comment: Actually, there is already one [issue](https://github.com/gregnb/mui-datatables/issues/643) opened for this.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue.  In my case, the warning was generated when my app was in a loading state. While loading data, my record count = 0 causing the page prop validator to throw the warning.

I found two ways to solve this:

***1. Hide pagination during the loading phase***

This should cure the warning but might make the UI feel "janky" by flickering while the page is loading.

***2. Use ternary logic to determine page value while loading***

This was my preferred solution, allowing me to continue displaying the pagination controls while loading the page.  The pagination information is not accurate during the brief loading period, but I find that to be more favorable than flickering.

To achieve the desired result, I created a constant to pass some logic into the `currentPage` prop for my table component:

```
// using a material-ui component in react web app
    
// sets page to 0 while loading

const pageWithLoading = {(page > 0 && records.length < rowsPerPage) ? 0 : page} 

<TablePagination curentPage={pageLoadingRange} {...props} />
```

I found a good discussion about these solutions [here on GitHub](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/15616)

Answer (score 1):

had the same issues, didnt want to mess with the version so i came up with a workaroud:

`Math.min(count, pageIndex)` did the trick for the `page` prop

```
<TablePagination
            rowsPerPageOptions={[2, 5, 10, 25, 50]}
            component="div"
            count={count}
            rowsPerPage={rowsPerPage}
            page={Math.min(count, pageIndex)}
            onPageChange={onPageIndexChange}
            onRowsPerPageChange={onRowsPerPageChange}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<TablePagination
          rowsPerPageOptions={[5, 10, 20, 25, 50, 75, 100]}
          component="div"
          count={rows.length}
          rowsPerPage={rowsPerPage}
          page={Math.min(rows.length, page)}
          onPageChange={handleChangePage}
          onRowsPerPageChange={handleChangeRowsPerPage}
        />
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).